# Can I bake light from Nishita Sky Texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, world

I want to bake the light from a Nishita Sky Texture to a model in Blender 2.9.
I thought it was possible, but now I can't manage to do it. I have Nishita set up as the sky in Cycles (obviously) but it won't bake on to the models.

Trying again with a simple scene below (even added a new Img Text to Bake in shader): NADA[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should work. What is the world node tree?

Comment: Thanks Lemon,
My world node is : skyTexture> Background>WorldOutput

Comment: Possibly, the issue is due to the fact that each face has two sides here. And both should be bake to. Don't know how the bake handle that.

Comment: Thanks @lemon : Interesting. but I have flipped the normals... so actually, only the insides are rendering  (except for one side which I separated & turned off)

Comment: Thanks @lemon : Interesting. but I have flipped the normals... so actually, only the insides are (should be) rendering (except for one side which I separated & turned off). The texture that renders is pure color has not lighting/shade datat on it..?

Comment: I've not tested more, but yes, have obtained flat colors too.

Comment: Still cant figure this out ... The Nishita sky looks great in Cycles but wont bake the right it casts...

Comment: It works. But you should have a volume as if not the bake does not know which side of the faces to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The bake is working correctly.

But if you are using flat sides (i.e. base cube with an open face), each side of the faces are baked and that makes conflicts.

Above in the picture, I have solidified that volume and unwrapped it.

I've used no other particular settings. Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: AWESOME! Yes yes I think it was that I had taken a cube, de attached sides and flipped Normals... I will have to investigate more with lighting rooms in this way w windows or doors. Thank you so much for sending the file ! That was a real help. 
Is there a way I can "accept" answer or reward you on forum for your help? Much appreciated !